# location.hash not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a simple if condition in a `$watch`

```
 $scope.$watch(location.hash, function(){
    if(location.hash == 'Payment-details')
    {
        alert('worked');
    }
});
```

This isn't working when I execute it

Comment: Are you using a router? If so, use route change events or use `$location` change events like `$locationChangeSuccess`

Comment: @Harish use $location instead of location

Comment: @KalaiselvanA will try it and let u know

Comment: It isn't working, I'm getting $$compose is not a function error

Comment: Yeah! it's not working properly..  are you using **$state** ?

Comment: No, I;m not using $STATE

Comment: $location.$$path will work

Answer (score 0):

`location.hash` will never equal "Payment-details": the hash (`#`) is included when reading the value.

Check for `location.hash == '#Payment-details'` instead.